# Backbone validation issue with simple form

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

I have written this code. Please help me to go through correct validation. I am trying this but the validation isn't getting called.
I have called the model from the view but it isn't getting called.
Do look into this. I am missing something very easy.
Please Help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>page1</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone-validation.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#">
            UserName: &nbsp;<input id="username" type="text" name="username" />
            <br />
            Password: &nbsp;<input id="password" type="password" name="password" />
            <br />
            Email: &nbsp;<input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" />
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#register').click(function(){
        var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
          validation: {
            username:{
            required: true,
            msg: 'Please enter Name'
            },
            email: [{
              required: true,
              msg: 'Please enter an email address'
            },{
              pattern: 'email',
              msg: 'Please enter a valid email'
            }]
          }
        });
        //var myModel = new Backbone.Model();
        var MyView=Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
        Backbone.Validation.bind(this);
            }
        });
        });
        //var myview=new MyView();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't actually creating a new model instance anywhere. `Backbone.Model.extend()` is just setting up the model it doesn't create an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Few things here:

1. Handle registration with your view not inside the click bound function
2. For model to `validate()` it should be extended with Backbone.Validation
3. If you just using blank binding you need to have `this.model` on the view

Following is pseudo code with some fixes. Try it.

---

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    // your model needs to have Validation Methods on it first
    _(this).extend(Backbone.Validation);
  },
  validation: {
    username:{
      required: true,
      msg: 'Please enter Name'
    },
    email: [{
      required: true,
      msg: 'Please enter an email address'
    },{
      pattern: 'email',
      msg: 'Please enter a valid email'
    }]
  }
});

//var myModel = new Backbone.Model();
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click #register': 'onRegister'
  },
  initialize: function(options){
    // Check if your this.model is set here
  },

  onRegister: function() {
    // this model is updated
    // write your own
    // validation will be triggered on save
    // 
    this.model.save();
    // or
    // this.model.validate();

  },

  render: function() {
    // you need to have a this.model
    // on your view in order to perform binding
    Backbone.Validation.bind(this);
  }
});



var myview = new MyView({model:new MyModel()});
myview.render();
```

And of course read the docs on [Backbone.Validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation)